# How to automatically resize a page when flipped in a Flex Mobile App

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

This may be a easy question but for some reason I can not seem to figure out how to get a page to automatically resize when changing from Landscape to Portrait in a Flex Mobile App.

i.e. I have a page that displays a menu to collect customer information, I have it laid out how I would like it for Portrait but if I switch to Landscape the formatting causes information to be left off of the screen.

This could be a question that I should probably know the answer to but does anyone have any ideas on how to go about something like this?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Example Page

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View backgroundColor="0xF7F9FD" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Page1">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


    <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">

        <s:VGroup verticalAlign="top" paddingTop="5" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center">
            <s:Image id="OLICLogo" verticalAlign="top" horizontalAlign="left" source="@Embed('PuritanLogo.jpg')"/>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup>
            <s:HGroup paddingTop="125" paddingLeft="40">
                <s:Label id="lblJoint" text="Joint Application" paddingTop="10"/>
                <s:CheckBox id="chkBoxJoint"/>  
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup>
            <s:HGroup paddingTop="110" paddingLeft="60">
                <s:Label id="lblTitle" paddingLeft="250" text="Personal Information" fontStyle="italic" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="16" paddingTop="10"/>   
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>


        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="375" paddingTop="200" horizontalAlign="center">
            <s:Line visible="true" xFrom="70" xTo="70" yFrom="300" yTo="870">
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x000000" weight="2"/>
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Line>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="40" paddingTop="180">
            <s:HGroup>
                <s:Label id="lblClient" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="16" paddingLeft="125" paddingRight="300" text="Client"/>
                <s:Label id="lblSpouse" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="16" text="Spouse"/>
            </s:HGroup>

        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="50" paddingTop="240">
            <s:Label id="lblCFName" paddingTop="10" text="First Name: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblCMName" paddingTop="20" text="Middle Name: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblCLName" paddingTop="20" text="Last Name: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblCDOB" paddingTop="20" text="DOB: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblCAddress" paddingTop="50" text="Address: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblCCity" paddingTop="20" text="City: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblCState" paddingTop="20" text="State: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblCZip" paddingTop="20" text="Zip Code: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblCEmail" paddingTop="50" text="Email Address: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblCPhone" paddingTop="20" text="Phone Number: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblCCell" paddingTop="20" text="Cell Phone: "/>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="170" paddingTop="240">
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtICFName"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtICMName"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtICLName"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtICDOB"/>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="170" paddingTop="430">
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtICAddress"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtICCity"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtICState"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtICZip"/>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="170" paddingTop="620">
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtICEmail"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtICPhone"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtICCell"/>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="410" paddingTop="240">
            <s:Label id="lblSFName" paddingTop="10" text="First Name: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblSMName" paddingTop="20" text="Middle Name: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblSLName" paddingTop="20" text="Last Name: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblSDOB" paddingTop="20" text="DOB: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblSAddress" paddingTop="50" text="Address: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblSCity" paddingTop="20" text="City: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblSState" paddingTop="20" text="State: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblSZip" paddingTop="20" text="Zip Code: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblSEmail" paddingTop="50" text="Email Address: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblSPhone" paddingTop="20" text="Phone Number: "/>
            <s:Label id="lblSCell" paddingTop="20" text="Cell Phone: "/>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="530" paddingTop="240">
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtISFName"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtISMName"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtISLName"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtISDOB"/>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="530" paddingTop="430">
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtISAddress"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtISCity"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtISState"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtISZip"/>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup paddingLeft="530" paddingTop="620">
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtISEmail"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtISPhone"/>
            <s:TextInput width="175" id="txtISCell"/>
        </s:VGroup>

        <s:VGroup paddingTop="800" paddingLeft="325" horizontalAlign="center">
            <s:Button id="btnContinue" click="btnContinue_clickHandler(event)" label="Continue"/>
        </s:VGroup>

    </s:Group>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function btnContinue_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                navigator.pushView(AFEAW.Page2);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read this article](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Auto_orient_your_mobile_application_to_the_device-18224.html).

In a nutshell, listen for the [StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/StageOrientationEvent.html#ORIENTATION_CHANGE) fired from the stage.

In your event listener; do stuff.

More info on [StageOrientationEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/StageOrientationEvent.html#ORIENTATION_CHANGE)

I'm not sure if your main application tag or view will fire this event.

Comment: This doesnt work in a View in FlashBuilder 4.6 when simulating an iOS device; nor does ORIENTATION_CHANGING.

Comment: I found the problem, you have to add the listener to the "stage" it wont get the event on the view. This article helped http://flashcodes.blogspot.com/2012/05/adobe-air-mobile-app-how-to-get-screen.html

Comment: @Mondain In this case; the version of Flash Builder does not matter--unless you're actually running Flash Builder on an iOS device; which would impress me. To be more specific you would have tell us which version of the Flex SDK and/or AIR SDK you are using.

Comment: FB on iOS yah that'll never happen. I'm building for Android and iOS using Flex 4.6 / Air 3.5. Don't misunderstand my comments, I've got it working; I'm simply saying the listener must be added to the stage since this event doesn't bubble up to the view.

Answer (score 0):

For mobile apps, I try to use constraints (top, bottom, left, right, verticalCenter, horizontalCenter) and percent widths/heights -- so that on orientation changes I don't worry so much. When I do worry, I rely on view states.

If you are using the Flex `View` class, the StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE is really only needed when you want to *prevent* the orientation change.

The reason is that the `View` class will automatically set a 'portrait' or 'landscape' view state for you, if your implementation simply includes a [portrait/landscape view state](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-7fff.html#WS8b1c39bd7e9fc364-2a6983c212a58b0f062-8000). Here's the `getCurrentState()` method of the `View` class:

```
public function getCurrentViewState():String
{
    var aspectRatio:String = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.aspectRatio;

    if (hasState(aspectRatio))
        return aspectRatio;

    // If the appropriate state for the orientation of the device
    // isn't defined, return the current state
    return currentState;
}
```

So if your `View` class has states like this:

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="portrait" stateGroups="portraitStates,whatever"/>
    <s:State name="landcsape" stateGroups="landscapeStates"/>
    <s:State name="landscapeWithControls" stateGroups="landscapeStates"/>
</s:states>
```

You can then use these stateGroup names with the powerful view state syntax in Flex 4 to handle all the rest of your orientation chores.

For views w/complex view states, it's handy to override `getCurrentViewState()`, and tack on your additional state names:

```
override public function getCurrentViewState():String
{
    var state:String = super.getCurrentViewState();
    if (someCondition)
    {
        state+="withControls";
    }
    return state;
}
```